# Django admin - TabularInline - display only a few objects from other model

Tags: python, django

Example models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    TYPES = (
        (0, 'Sci-fi')
        (1, 'Biography')
    )

    title = models.CharField(...)
    book_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPES)

 class Connect(models.Model):
     book1 = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name='book_1')
     book2 = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name='book_2')
```

I want do one think, display Connect as TabularInline in Book, but only show Connect where **book1__book_type = 0**

I try do it like this:

```
class ConnectFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_queryset'):
            qs = super(ConnectionFormSet, self).get_queryset().filter('book1__book_type':0)
            self._queryset = qs
        return self._queryset



class InlineConnectn(admin.TabularInline):
    fk_name = 'book1'
    model = Connect
    extra = 0
    formset = ConnectFormSet
```

But it's not working like I want. Still all Connections are visible in a list of Connect in the TabularInline.

Works only save Connect (only Connect with book1__book_type = 0 are saved).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`formfield_for_foreignkey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) should do what you want:

```
class InlineConnectn(admin.TabularInline):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "book1":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Foo.objects.filter(book1__book_type=1)
        return super(InlineConnectn, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```